# Programmatically add AdMob banner

Tags: swift, admob

Is there a way to implement adMob banners programmatically so that I can remove them with an in-app purchase (IAP)?

Something like the iAd:

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
```

When there is that line of code the ads are displayed, else the space is used for other views, like a uitableview.

Comment: So Zac, I am a bit confused, did it work for you ?

Comment: Explain a bit more please, I am not abandoning if I can help you !

Comment: Now it worked, thanks @Coder1000

Comment: Happy to help ! I upvoted your quesion ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is what I used for my IAP, and it works like a charm. It's executed once the IAP is bought.

```
func removeAds(){
    banner.removeFromSuperview()
    bannerGoogle.removeFromSuperview()
    outRemoveAds.removeFromSuperview()
    restorePurchases.removeFromSuperview()
    let theValue = 10
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(theValue, forKey: "val")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

Just create IBOutlets for your ads.

Comment: And to add the banner to the page?

Comment: That's exactly the idea. Add a bannerview with the interface builder and create an IBOutlet linking to it.

Comment: But will the banner view disappear and the rest of the page adapt to the space left by it?

Comment: It did for me. I don't see why it wouldn't for you.

Comment: If it doesn't, then you might need to work on your constraints again.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following library. It makes it easy to implement and remove banner ads.

https://github.com/chrisjp/CJPAdController

Comment: Please don't put link only answers. What happens once the link becomes invalid in your opinion ? Please provide the link only for reference and write an answer that is self-contained.